# Uploading an array of images gives problems (ASIHTTPRequest)

Tags: iphone, arrays, image, http, upload

I'm using the ASIHTTPRequest Library to send multiple images via a webservice. I've got an array of 2 images and like to send them. However only the latest image is being uploaded. I think it's because of the fact that image 2 is overwriting image 1 because their names are the same.

How can I change the name of every image that's within my array so that all the files are being uploaded properly?

Here's my code

```
NSString* filename2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image.jpeg", i];
NSString *strURL = @"www.thisismyurl.com"; 
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setPostValue:@"This is sample text..." forKey:@"text"];

for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    [request addData:[array objectAtIndex:i] withFileName:filename2  andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d", i + 1]];
}   
[request startAsynchronous];
```

**EDIT**

Here's my code for so far. First I'm calling my images from my documents directory -> Convert it to NSData -> Putting the NSData in a Array -> Putting the array inside the 'addData: request'. How can I can I give every image a specific name when it's being posted?

```
NSString *docDir2 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *pngFilePath2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/foto2.jpeg",docDir2];
            UIImage *img2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath2];
            NSData *imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img2,0.75);

            NSString *docDir3 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *pngFilePath3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/foto3.jpeg",docDir3];
            UIImage *img3 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath3];
            NSData *imageData3 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img3, 0.75);

            [array addObject:imageData2];
            [array addObject:imageData3];

            [img2 release];
            [img3 release];

            if ([array count] > 0) {

                NSString *strURL = @"this is my url"; 
                ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
                [request setDelegate:self];
                [request setPostValue:@"This is sample text..." forKey:@"text"];
                for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {

                    [request addData:[array objectAtIndex:i] withFileName:@"image.jpeg"  andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d", i + 1]];

                }   
                [request startAsynchronous];


            }
            else {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"You have to make some pictures" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertView show];
                [alertView release];
            }
```

Comment: What exactly is inside of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely your filename is wrong. `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image.jpeg", i];` is not a valid format.

```
NSString *strURL = @"www.thisismyurl.com"; 
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setPostValue:@"This is sample text..." forKey:@"text"];

for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {

    [request addData:[array objectAtIndex:i] 
        withFileName:[NSString strinWithFormat:@"image_%d.jpg", i+1] 
      andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d", i + 1]];

 }   
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however it's still not working (I replaced [request addData:[array objectAtIndex:i] withFileName:filename2  andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d", i + 1]]; -> [request addData:[array objectAtIndex:i] withFileName:@"image.jpeg"  andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d", i + 1]]; any clues?

Comment: so again you a referring to the same filename.

Comment: I'm aware of that. That's my I'm asking :-)

Comment: woops, you're answer did the job. Thanks a lot vikingosegundo!